# how to verify that sbin/init isn't infected?

Tags: security, init, rootkit

for sometime chkrootkit has been showing sbin/init as being infected with SuckIt rootkit. early this year when the warning first appeared a quick google search indicated that it was most likely a false positive.

I did a check again today and again chkrootkit says sbin/init is infected.

A few articles suggested that one could verify sbin/init with RPM.

i installed rpm and tried the command :

> rpm -qf /sbin/init

and it returned:

> file /sbin/init is not owned by any package

i also read somewhere that /sbin/init is supposed to be a syslink (although that was for a different distro) and on my system /sbin/init appears to be an executable file.

the command,

> ls -l /sbin/init

returns the following:

> -rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 252080 Jul 18 15:18 /sbin/init

is there anyway i could verify that /sbin/init hasnt really been infected?

I am running ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my laptop (not connected on a lan)

thank you.

EDIT:

i installed and ran rkhunter

its check against the "SuckIt" rootkit was negative, however it later reported:

> Performing additional rootkit checks
>       Suckit Rookit additional checks                          [ Warning ]

and,

```
Checking the local host...

  Performing system boot checks
    **Checking for local host name                             [ Found ]
    Checking for system startup files                        [ Found ]**
    Checking system startup files for malware                [ None found ]

  Performing group and account checks
    **Checking for passwd file                                 [ Found ]**
    Checking for root equivalent (UID 0) accounts            [ None found ]
    Checking for passwordless accounts                       [ None found ]
    Checking for passwd file changes                         [ None found ]
    Checking for group file changes                          [ None found ]
    Checking root account shell history files                [ None found ]

  Performing system configuration file checks
    **Checking for SSH configuration file                      [ Not found ]
    Checking for running syslog daemon                       [ Found ]**
    Checking for syslog configuration file                   [ Found ]
    Checking if syslog remote logging is allowed             [ Not allowed ]

  Performing filesystem checks
    Checking /dev for suspicious file types                  [ Warning ]
    Checking for hidden files and directories                [ Warning ]


Rootkit checks...
    Rootkits checked : 292
    Possible rootkits: 1
    Rootkit names    : Suckit Rookit (additional checks)
```

Should i be worried?

UPDATE:
after looking at the rkhunter log i found out that the reason it has been warning against a possible suckit infection was because there were more than one hard links to /sbin/init, which was my own doing. after removing the additional hard link rkhunter reports a clean system.

so basically it's just chkrootkit reporting Suckit infection which is a possible false positive.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the integrity of /sbin/init by installing the "debsums" package and running `debsums -c`.

This will check all files on the system and tell you if they've been modified since they were installed from their .deb files (if they came from .deb files).

If it comes back without reporting any changes, /sbin/init hasn't been modified.

If you want to check a particular package specifically without examining the whole system (which will generate a lot of I/O and may take time), you can find out what package it's in using `dpkg -S /path/to/filename`, for example:

`# dpkg -S /sbin/init
upstart: /sbin/init`

This tells you the file was installed by the "upstart" package (on 14.04 at least).

You can then use `dpkg --verify upstart` and it will tell you if any files have been modified from the base upstart .deb.

Answer (score -1):

clamav will probably detect this virus?, don't know how to clean files though. You probably need to start a recovery session, mount the live cd manually. Copy init off the cd onto your hard disk.